# How to make background transparent in android camera app

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am making an android camera app but I am not able to set all layouts transparent so as to create an immersive effect.

My Code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/control"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/shutter"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_info"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_info" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried all the methods as given in other Q and A but to no avail.
Please help me.

Comment: What you mean by transparent background ? can you post the expected output ?  Or explain more about question .

Comment: http://uigarage.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/tumblr_o8c4413ndJ1ul8y65o1_1280-1.jpg             
 I want the view as clear around the shutter as depicted in the image.

Comment: The view finder ?? The rectangle shape in center ??

Comment: No. I was talking about the transparency in the whole UI. It is not coming in my UI. there is a black layout around the shutter button like in google camera which has the grey portion like in this image.I want it as in my image.        https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQx4OJwmmjXLDzN89l6PoLBYNSVWYaQ7N7xHM0S8fo84n5qo-5yMw

Answer (score 0):

As much as i understood from question . Below layout should work .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/control"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/shutter"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_info"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_info" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```